# LNK 1168: Cannot open .exe VS 2013, Windows Audio is using the .exe

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Trying to compile a VS 2013 C++ application and Im getting the LNK1168 cannot open .\bin\foo\bar\foobar.exe for writing.

I've followed other articles. Application Experience is enabled and running. Ive restarted VS. Cleaned and tried to rebuild. Checked the Task Mgr to make sure the application isn't running too.

My only success is after a full system reboot.

Nothing is working except the system reboot. I went to the directory and noticed that when I tried to delete the .exe that is currently there (from a previous successful build) it gives me an error saying that the operation cannot be completed because it is open in Windows Audio..

Has anybody dealt with this before? Restarting my whole OS to build is not going to work for me much longer.

The project is mapped to a D: drive (i.e. not located on C:).

Comment: Sometimes a prog is executing without a window. You can terminate it with the Task Manager.

Comment: @Ripi2 I did that, not running in the task mgr